# Javascript jQuery click no result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question has surely been asked a million times but I can't find anything specific to what I'm stuck with.

It seems that nothing inside my `<script>` tags is working, but I'm not sure why.

Here's the setup:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link href="~/Content/workflow.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title></title>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ztree/js/jquery.ztree.all-3.5.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#btn-cancel').click(function(){
                alert("Button click worked!");
            });
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-center" style="margin:20px 0 0 60%;">
      <input type="button" class="form-btn" id="btn-cancel" value="Cancel" style="margin-right:50px" />                
    </div>
</body>
```

There are some other bits and bats of script and HTML in there, but for neatness I've left them out. The general layout is as shown above.

Clicking the cancel button has no effect.

I've tried for various buttons, singled out various bits, deleted whole sections of script, etc etc, and nothing works, so I think the script section itself is setup wrong in some way.

Any guidance much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: you can't put inline javascript inside a script tag that has a src attribute - the inline script is ignored - see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src)

Comment: you are calling the library two times

Comment: just remove `src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"` from your inline script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last script tag, you should replace this

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

And so, your custom script tag should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $('#btn-cancel').click(function(){
      alert("Button click worked!");
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you may notice that `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is also the first script loaded :p

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. The code I'm working with is part of a major project so a lot of what I was looking at was a copy-paste job. Turns out the problem was a little deeper than I realised anyway. The button was in an "Ajax.BeginForm()" section, which is something totally new to me so I didn't think it would have much relevance to basic button clicks. Turns out that was the problem and now it's all fixed. Apologies for the total newb nature of my question. I've just started a new job as an intern/trainee, still very new to most areas of web development..!

Comment: That's all right, mate. You'll find SO to be very helpful. Good luck with your new job!

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#btn-cancel').click(function(){
                alert("Button click worked!");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Add type="text/javascript" attribute is ocd-patient-friendly, :)

Comment: @tibetty agreed :D

Comment: "HTML5 spec urges authors to omit the attribute rather than provided[sic] a redundant MIME type" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type - i.e. don't use `type` for javascript scripts

Answer (score 0):

you can't add like this

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#btn-cancel').click(function(){
            alert("Button click worked!");
        });
    });

</script>
```

change it into

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#btn-cancel').click(function(){
            alert("Button click worked!");
        });
    });
```

and remove `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">` because you already defined it in the first.

Your code should look like this

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ztree/js/jquery.ztree.all-3.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#btn-cancel').click(function(){
            alert("Button click worked!");
        });
    });

</script>
```

moreover besides i prefer using `onclick()` with button,

```
<input type="button" class="form-btn" id="btn-cancel" value="Cancel" style="margin-right:50px" onclick="BtnClick()"/>

function BtnClick(){
    alert("Button click worked!");
}
```

Comment: Your first script tag is missing `>`